# How can we run specific CSV rows (Test Case) in Karate API

Tags: api, karate, data-driven-tests

I have 10 data driven API test cases defined in CSV file in 10 rows and my feature file generates dynamic requests from data sheet and execute the test cases. But I wanted to run only one Test case out of 10. Is there any way that I can trigger only one test case in Karate API ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this for CSV files, sorry. If you have a normal `Examples` table you can append the line-number of the row to the feature file like this:

```
some.feature:15
```